# jquery list show strange behaviour in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, html-lists

I have made a page which has ol > li in which the li's are hidden using css.
Now i am hsowing the li using jquery code

```
$('ol#update li').show();
```

The page here at [void](http://nvoids.co.cc/shouts.jsp)

Now this is showing right on ie9 but somehow the behaviour is very very strange in
chrome 14.0.835.

If i refresh the page 5 times then 3-4 times the page does not shows the li's

Please help me out with chrome here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just added the js before the eof body tag html in the page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shouts.js"></script>
</body>
```

thanks